# Reverse string time and space complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have written different python codes to reverse a given string. But, couldn't able to figure the which one among them is efficient. Can someone point out the differences between these algorithms using time and space complexities?

```
def reverse_1(s):
      result = ""
      for i in s : 
          result = i + result
      return result

def reverse_2(s): 
      return s[::-1]
```

There are [already some solutions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python), but I couldn't find out the time and space complexity. I would like to know how much space `s[::-1]` will take?

Comment: `reverse_1` is the worst reverse routine you can possibly write. With `O(n*2)` complexity. Stick to the second one which is `O(n)` and doesn't use a loop

Comment: But, what if the interviewer doesn't accept it. It's kind of cheating. Is there any other way to reverse a string in python.

Comment: A suggestion for a quick test is use timeit feature from ipython console. This way: `timeit reverse_1('blabla')`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `O(n + n)` is the same as `O(n)`

Comment: @VenkataGogu if using best features of python is cheating then I don't know... you can boast with alternatives like I provided in my answer, & the argumentation. I doubt an interviewer would object that.

Comment: @smac89 yes and? the join method is O(n) but is still slower than the slice method.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, so it can't be worse than `O(n)` as per your comment

Comment: @smac89 `reverse_1` is worse: it's `O(n*n)`. Try that on a really large string, it never ends because it has to copy the string. So basically `n*(n-1)//2` copies

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you wrote `O(n * 2)` no? Maybe you mean `O(n ^ 2)`? Anyways, you're right, `O(n*n)` is worse than `O(n)`

Comment: @smac89 ah you're right, my bad. I meant n*n or n^2. I had to close as duplicate, after reading the original question & answers, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, why is this question duplicate? I have already seen that post before posting my question. All answers said `s[::-1]` is a way but never mentioned the time and space complexity for that statement.

Comment: I'd very much like this question _not_ to be a duplicate (I answered it) but if you read the answer of the other question, you notice that my answer just sums up what is said here, and comes to the same conclusions. Maybe you could edit to explain why it isn't a duplicate. I'd very much like to reopen but I feel that this isn't appropriate ATM.

Comment: Yes, obviously to test this, I can use `timeit` to know which one function works great. But, key factor for me is space which never mentioned in that post.

Comment: edited my answer to reflect the space complexity aspect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without even trying to bench it (you can do it easily), `reverse_1` would be dead slow because of many things:

- loop with index
- constantly adding character to string, creating a copy each time.

So, slow because of loop & indexes, `O(n*n)` time complexity because of the string copies, `O(n)` complexity because it uses extra memory to create temp strings (which are hopefully garbage collected in the loop).

On the other hand `s[::-1]`:

- doesn't use a visible loop
- returns a string without the need to convert from/to list
- uses compiled code from python runtime

So you cannot beat it in terms of time & space complexity and speed.

If you want an alternative you can use:

```
''.join(reversed(s))
```

but that will be slower than `s[::-1]` (it has to create a list so `join` can build a string back). It's interesting when other transformations are required than reversing the string.

Note that unlike C or C++ languages (as far as the analogy goes for strings) **it is not possible** to reverse the string with `O(1)` space complexity because of the *immutability* of strings: you need twice the memory because string operations cannot be done in-place (this can be done on list of characters, but the `str` <=> `list` conversions use memory)

Comment: Can you post some answer somewhere between these algorithms like `O(n) or O(logn) ...`

Comment: there's no way you can have `O(log(n)) complexity here. It's clearly `O(n)` at best.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in `O(n) time and O(1) space`.

Comment: on a list of characters it is possible, but not a string.